# Kendo Grid Datepicker save format

Tags: datepicker, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a grid that has a date field.

When a json POST is made to the server, the data that's sent looks like this: "2013-09-13T16:40:34.301Z", and a PUT looks like this: "2013-09-13T04:00:00.000Z".  So it looks like the same format, but the POST is including some screwy time value and the PUT some other screwy time value (neither of which are correct).

I want to only send the DATE.  Anyone have any idea?

```
                kendoGrid.....
                model: {
                id: "ID",
                fields: {
                    ID: {
                        editable: false,
                        type: "number"
                    },

                    START_DATE: {
                        field: "START_DATE",
                        type: "date",
                        format: "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}",
                        validation: {
                            required: true
                        }
                    },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Data](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#configuration-transport.update.data) function (of the upload or create config) to send that date in a different format or use the [parameterMap](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#configuration-transport.parameterMap) to change the existing format.